# How to get jupyter notebook theme in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am a data scientist use jupyter notebook a lot and also have started to do lot of development work and use Vscode for development. so how can I get Jupyter notebook theme in vscode as well? I know how to open a Jupyter notebook in vscode by installing an extension but I wanted to know how to get Jupyter notebook theme for vs code. so it gets easier to switch between both ide without training eyes

Answer (score 4):

I created a new theme that is now on the vscode marketplace!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sam-the-programmer.jupyter-theme

Go to the link above, or search in the VS Code marketplace `sam-the-programmer.jupyter-theme`. Install the first one that comes up. This then allows you to press <kbd>F1</kbd>, search for **Change Colour Theme** and then select `Jupyter Theme`. Done!

It should look like...

[image: Image of what it looks like]

Hope you like it!

Comment: Very nice! By any chance did you make a dark version too? If so, I couldn't find it in your github account

Comment: I could! I'll try to have it done as soon as possible, I'll reply to you @pedrosaurio

Comment: I have completed it @pedrosaurio but it is not incredible, I'll keep updating it.

Comment: I will check it out!

Comment: I have VSCode 1.62.3 and when I try to install the extension I get an error 'Can't install extension because it is not compatible with the current version of Visual Studio Code. Any way to get the theme for my version? Thanks

Comment: The earliest it supports is 1.63.0, but it is very easy to upgrade VS Code. By running the installer from their website, it will update VS Code, without changing your extensions or settings. They will remain, as will your file history, etc. @jmich738

Comment: @pedrosaurio I updated it a while ago and if you want to contribute, the repo is at https://github.com/sam-the-programmer/vscode-jupyter-theme

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your VScode's settings by:

1- Go to your `Jupyter extension` => `Extension settings` => and *check* `"Ignore Vscode Theme"`.

2- Click on `File` => `preference`=> `color Theme`

3-  Select the theme you need.

You can download the theme extension from VSCode's extension store, for example: Markdown Theme Kit; Material Theme Kit.

**Note:**
You need to restart or reload VSCode to see the changes.

Comment: Sadly, the "Ignore Vscode Theme" setting is being deprecated. see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6448 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/pull/7455

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the jupyter notebook in VSCode is provided by the python extension. Therefore, although it supports the use of the jupyter notebook, it does not support providing theme specifically for jupyter notebook.

You could refer to the following ways to change the color and highlight of jupyter notebook:

1. Click on'`File`','`preference`','`color Theme`', then, select the theme you need. Reference:[Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes).
2. Download the theme extension from VSCode's extension store, for example:Markdown Theme Kit;Material Theme Kit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own notebook theme. It looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp2Fr.png.
To find the required parameter in the JSON file, you can use 'Developer Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes, and then change the colors you need in the JSON file.
JSON located in /Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/file.json.
Or if u want use custom theme like me(i used Slack Theme) JSON of extension theme located in /users/user_name/.vscode/extensions/theme_name/themes/file.json. This video also can help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su-cNLe0dgw&ab_channel=RAZR.
And then using 'inspect element' in browser copy colors and past to json scopes.